# Cronometro hecho con hilos se retrasa unos milisegundos

Tags: java, hilos

Estoy haciendo el juego de buscaminas, el código de mi cronometro es así:

```
public class Cronometro extends Thread{
    
    int segundos = 1, numeroUnico;
    static boolean hiloCorriendo = true;
    boolean seInicio = false;    

    public void run() {
        try {         
            
            while (hiloCorriendo) {
                
                if (segundos <= 9) {
                    Buscaminas.tiempo.setText("0" + "0" + segundos);
                } else if (segundos <= 99) {
                    Buscaminas.tiempo.setText("0" + segundos);
                } else if (segundos <= 999) {
                    Buscaminas.tiempo.setText("" + segundos);
                }
                
                segundos++;

                System.out.println("hilo : " + Thread.currentThread().getName()); //me ayudo a saber si se hacian dos hilos
                
                if(seInicio == false){
                    numeroUnico = Buscaminas.numHilo;//numHilo aumenta 1 al darle a reiniciar
                    seInicio = true;
                }
                
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                
                hiloCorriendo = true;
                
                if(numeroUnico != Buscaminas.numHilo){
                    hiloCorriendo = false;
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            
        }        
    }
}
```

El código de el panel reiniciar:

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
        if (iniciado == true) {
                
            if(numHilo < 100){
                numHilo++;
            } else {
                numHilo = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Y el codigo de `mousePressed` que tengo en los cuadros donde se da click para poner una bandera o ver si no hay una mina, es este:

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    if (iniciado == false) {
        Cronometro.hiloCorriendo = true;
        Cronometro hilo = new Cronometro();
        hilo.start();
        iniciado = true;
    }
}
```

Pero  tengo un problema y es que el hilo aunque duerma 1 segundo al salir del `Thread.sleep(1000);` tiene que hacer otros procesos que se demoran unos milisegundos (eso depende del rendimiento del pc) y estos van a hacer que al volver de nuevo al `Thread.sleep(1000);` en vez de que pase 1 segundo, pasen, por ejemplo 1 segundo y 2 milisegundos, esto a los 2 minutos o 3 ya se empieza a notar mucho, y hace que se retrase el cronometro por 2 o 3 segundos, entonces, ustedes saben si hay alguna manera de evitar eso?

Comment: Ningún cronómetro de software será totalmente válido, siempre retrasan... te explico por qué. Tu le dices a tu código, oye duerme durante 1 segundo y luego suma 1. Ok eso está genial, tu código va a dormir durante 1000ms, y luego sumar 1.... y luego tardará unos 10ms más entre cargar todo en memoria, restaurar los valores de las variables, etc etc. Tu código hace más cosas que dormir 1000ms y sumar 1, y de hecho, incluso sumar 1 le llevará algo de tiempo (poco, pero eventualmente acaba siendo algo). Por eso los relojes de software puro no suelen ser buena idea

Comment: Ten en cuenta que el procesador de tu pc no está trabajando únicamente con tu aplicación, un pc mantiene docenas o cientos de procesos en funcionamiento, y todos van tomando su trozo de tiempo de CPU, el proceso de mover cosas a la cpu y moverlas a fuera también cuesta tiempo. No vas a poder evitar esto, porque no tienes un [sistema operativo en tiempo real](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_operativo_de_tiempo_real). Además, has de tener en cuenta que durante el `Thread.sleep` el hilo está totalmente irresponsivo, no responderá a tus eventos de click!

Comment: si, eso es a lo que me refiero, yo puse el cronometro de mi juego al lado de el de mi pc, y aunque mi juego tenia 1 segundo de ventaja, al pasar 1 minuto era al reves, entonces no hay manera de hacer un cronometro estable? le llevo echando cabeza desde hace unos dias y no logro encontrar la respuesta.

Comment: he visto que muchos usan `scheduledexecutorservice` pero no consigo entenderlo muy bien, todo esta en ingles y no es muy entendible, si alguno sabe utilizarlo para lo que necesito seria de gran ayuda.

Comment: Incluso un `ScheduledExecutorService` te va a garantizar que tu código se ejecute *después de X delay*, no que se ejecute **exactamente** tras ese delay.

Comment: mmm ya, yo compare el cronometro de mi buscaminas con el juego original, y el juego original con el de mi pc y el de el original tenia el tiempo sin retrasos, por eso se que si se puede hacer un cronometro estable

Comment: Claro que se puede. Todos los PC llevan un reloj que no se retrasa absolutamente nada.... porque es una pieza de hardware físico. Dejas que tu thread duerma durante 1s, y al despertar lees el tiempo de tu pc en vez de usar tu variable. El tiempo de tu pc te dará el momento exacto en el que te encuentras, y con la anterior lectura sabrás exactamente cuánto tiempo ha pasado desde la última vez que saliste del `sleep`, así puedes actualizar tu variable acorde a eso :) Es decir, permites que tu programa duerma *al menos 1000ms* y luego lees el tiempo real del pc, y actualizas acorde a ese tiempo

Comment: mmm, me podrias decir como puedo leer el tiempo de mi pc?, y que variable es la que tengo que cambiar?, si puedes pon la respuesta abajo para que pueda marcarla  como la mejor

Comment: oye, intente lo que me dijiste pero el problema es que de igual manera, al leer el tiempo, se demora unos milisegundos, y podria cuadrar el `Thread.sleep(1000)` a `Thread.sleep(980)` pero no hay punto miedo porque en un intento puede salir de una manera, y en otro intento de otra, eso depende del rendimiento del pc (cuantas apps tenga abierta en ese momento) y mas.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que podrías agregar una rutina que calcule tu delay y a eso se lo sumas o restas a tu cronometro para que quede mas "a tiempo". normalmente ese tipo de cálculos que hace la computadora no utilizan tanto tiempo y no será tan notable.

Comment: Es lo mismo, ya que al hacer el calculo de cuanto tiempo demora en hacer la accion de sumar 1 y ponerlo en la interfaz, tambien va a demorar unos milisegundos hacer ese calculo y quedaria igual que si no lo hiciera.

Comment: Cuando tengas suficiente reputación podrás hacer comentarios a las respuestas, por mientras revisa [Como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)